# Remote Gremlin Server and Concurrent Requests for Janus Graph

Tags: gremlin, janusgraph, gremlin-server

I am using Embedded Gremlin Server with Janus Graph but I have noticed problem with concurrent requests

Consider there are two types of gremlin queries

1- Query that scans related records at hop =1 may be less than or equal to 1000 related items
2- Query that scans related records at hop =3 may be 500,000 or more records

When I ran both the above separately the first set of queries finishes in few milliseconds
and the second query goes timed out as we have set the query time out limit to say 10 seconds, as the second query is trying to query the super node as far as my understanding it is best suited for OLAP related traversal may be using Apache Spark

But when both the above query run parallelly then if the second query comes first then gremlin server add the other small queries in the queue and they also took more than a minute to complete instead in few milliseconds, looks like gremlin server add such queries in a queue once the big query is trying to scan 500,000 records and once it is timed out the other small queries got the chance to succeed.

Just wondering if there is any performance tuning option present at the Gremlin server side that can help improve the scalability?

We are using Cassandra as the backend using Caching at the Cassandra side could help in the performance improvement for such concurrent requests? Or is there any way to use redis or other distributed cache at the gremlin server side to reduce to overall latency in case of concurrent requests?

Comment: how are these queries being submitted when you do them in parallel? are you using a session?

Comment: Hi Stephen, These queries are being submitted using the cached GraphTraversalSource object that we created at the startup of the Rest API, and using the same object for multiple API calls, not using any separate specific session though, thanks for you response.

Comment: if you have only one large request, i wouldn't expect it to become a bottleneck for others unless you were using a session (which is single threaded). how many additional smaller queries are being sent in addition to the large one?

Comment: we tried with more than 500 queries per second with a mix of smaller queries and the query that scans 500,000 related items from the super node, once gremlin server tries to execute the query involving super node, it looks like other queries kept in the queue until the super node query fails/timedout

Comment: Gremlin Server should only queue once all threads in the `gremlinPool` are consumed. So presuming the server has enough resources to continue to process the small queries in that `gremlinPool` the one long query should not affect the small shorter ones. Perhaps you should profile the server a bit to see what state it is in? Maybe you need to configure more memory for the server? or a larger instance?

Comment: Thanks Stephen, I will try to play with the server configurations will try to see if vertical scaling helps, really appreciate your help :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253724/discussion-between-a-r-khan-and-stephen-mallette).